# calculate mean and variance from multivariate probability-generating function in random walks

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose in a biased random walk, $r(i,n)$ is the probability that a particle appears at position $i$ at time $n$. The corresponding probability generating function is 
$$
R(z,s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty r(i,n)z^i s^n.
$$
Suppose by some means I obtain the probability generating function, and I want to know
$$
\mu(n)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty r(i,n)i
$$
and
$$
\sigma^2(n)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty r(i,n)\left[i-\mu(n)\right]^2
$$

**My question** is: how to get from $R(z,s)$ to $\mu(n)$ and $\sigma^2(n)$ (presumably by differentiation and other operations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally :

$$(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R)(z,s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,n)iz^{i-1}s^n $$

$$(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R))(z,s)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,n)iz^{i-1}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}s^{n-k} $$

So that :

$$(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R))(1,0)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,n)i\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}1^{i-1}0^{n-k}=k!\mu(k) $$

Whence :

$$\mu(k)=\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R))(1,0) $$

For the standard deviation it should be mostly the same, remark (by the same formal argument) that :

$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,k)i^2=\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}z(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R)))(1,0) $$

$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,k)=\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}R)(1,0)$$

Since :

$$\sigma^2(n)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,n)[i-\mu(n)]^2=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,n)i^2-\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}r(i,n)\mu(n)^2$$

You get :

$$\sigma^2(k)=\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}z(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R)))(1,0)- \frac{1}{k!}(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}R)(1,0)[\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial s^k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R))(1,0)]^2$$

Comment: thanks for the very detailed derivations! I wonder where I can find textbooks covering multivariate probability generating functions. So far I haven't found any detailed treatments in the textbooks on statistics and stochastic processes I have read.

Comment: @wdg, when it comes to generating functions, I read Wilf's generatingfunctionology, you can download a version here https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html. For your purpose you might want to read part 4.1, it explicitely refers to probability generating functions.